# Reverse recovery method for carrier lifetime measurement

Tags: transient, pn-junction, lifetime

I have used reverse recovery method for measurement of carrier lifetime. I have used a simple setup consisting of a function generator, a resistance and DUT (device under test). In a conventional transient response, there is a constant current phase and a recovery phase, and effective carrier lifetime can be determined from these equations in this [link](https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/semi_en/kap_8/advanced/t8_1_1.html).

But transient response which I have measured, has no constant current phase, and after switching, begins decaying to reverse saturation current.

[image]

My question is, why there is not constant current phase in transient response? Is it related to If/Ir ratio? Is there any consideration about If/Ir ratio in reverse recovery method?
Thank you.

Comment: That's about what I've seen before. I'm not sure about the article and I don't want to read it, right now. But take a look at this link: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/technical-articles/Understanding-Diode-Reverse-Recovery-and-Its-Effect-on-Switching-Losses.pdf and look particularly at Figure 
II-5 there.

Comment: @jonk Updated link: https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/351267/Understanding-Diode-Reverse-Recovery-and-Its-Effect-on-Switching-Losses.pdf

Comment: @TimWilliams You must be working on your archeology, or something. This is more than 5 years ago!!

Comment: @jonk Stuff keeps bubbling up from the community bot... or I'm using this site wrong :^)

Answer (score 2):

The period from 5 000 065 to 5 000 092 ns is the constant current region.

The test conditions use a resistive square wave source, so the storage time (where the diode is essentially still fully on, V near Vf) is a mostly flat region, until diode voltage reverses and the recovery tail ensues.

It's not so much that the current is constant in this region, as that the input and output are still connected by an on-state diode.  And the input happens to be constant, so the output will be as well.

This is different from power diode tests, which use a current ramp of indeterminate magnitude (i.e., the longer t<sub>rr</sub> is, the more peak current I<sub>rr</sub> will flow).  The current ramp is set by some combination of gate drive speed into a switching device (MOSFET/IGBT), and loop inductance (setting a maximum dI/dt = V<sub>in</sub>/L<sub>s</sub>).  Here there is no constant current region, because current is never constant (well, except for the instant when current peaks), giving the familiar two-phase waveform (t<sub>a</sub>, diode on with low voltage drop; t<sub>b</sub>, diode off with high voltage drop and recovery current flow; t<sub>rr</sub> = t<sub>a</sub> + t<sub>b</sub>, softness = t<sub>b</sub>/t<sub>a</sub>).

Answer (score 0):

I changed (increased) If/Ir ratio and then a constant current phase appeared in reverse recovery curve. for more detail, see the links below:

[Reverse transient of a p-n junction](https://dr.lib.iastate.edu/handle/20.500.12876/73831), G. Garlick, Iowa State University, 1962

[Reverse transient response in a PIN diode](https://dr.lib.iastate.edu/handle/20.500.12876/74077), A. Anderson, Iowa State University, 1963